# JQuery POST executes twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a registration form and i made some conditions for checking email existance in db but when i create a new account with existent email it return me 1 that is (Email existed) and that is ok , but when i create a new account with a fresh email it returns me again 1 .. and it should return me -> 4 that is for (Account creation with success) see my code bellow:

```
 $('#acord').on('change', function(){
   this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
 $("#formreg").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".inreg").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Verificam informatiile..');
  var $form = $(this),
    acord  = $form.find("[type='checkbox'][name=acord]").val(),
    nume   = $form.find("[type='text'][name=nume]").val(),
    email  = $form.find("[type='email'][name='email']").val(),
    parola = $form.find("[type='password'][name='parola']").val(),
    varsta = $form.find("[type='text'][name='varsta']").val(),
    url = 'inc/sql/register-user.php';
  setTimeout(function() {
    var posting = $.post(url, {
      nume:   nume,
      email:  email,
      parola: parola,
      varsta: varsta,
      acord:  acord
    });
    posting.done(function(data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        swal({
          title: "Adresa de mail exista",
          text: "Adresa de email "+email+" este deja folosita.",
          type: "error",
          timer: 4000,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
        $(".inreg").html('INREGISTREAZA-TE');
      } else if (data == 2) {
        swal({
          title: "Ups!",
          text: "Adresa de email nu este valida.",
          type: "error",
          timer: 4000,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
        $(".inreg").html('INREGISTREAZA-TE');
      } else if (data == 3) {
        swal({
          title: "Ups!",
          text: "Parola prea lunga, trebuie sa contina intre 5 si 10 caractere. ",
          type: "error",
          timer: 4000,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
        $(".inreg").html('INREGISTREAZA-TE');
      } else if (data == 4) {
        swal({
          title: "Felicitari! " + nume + "",
          text: "Contul a fost inregistrat in baza noastra de date. Nu uitati sa adaugati momentele. Va dorim mult succes!",
          type: "success",
          timer: 2100,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
        $(".inreg").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Va logam automat in cont..');
        setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = "?p=contul-meu";}, 3000);
      } else if (data == 5) {
        swal({
          title: "Termeni si conditii neacceptate!",
          text: "Ne pare rau, dar ca sa te poti inregistra pe aceasta platforma trebuie sa fi de acord cu termenii si conditiile noastre!",
          type: "warning",
          timer: 4300,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
       }
       $(".inreg").html('INREGISTREAZA-TE');
    })
  }, 3000);

});
}).change();
```

Comment: What does this method do **.change()**;?

Comment: is for term and conditions accord 1= checked and 0 = uncheck and the thing is that in browser console is executing the php file twice

Comment: It's time to learn about `switch` so you can avoid this wild `else if` chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#acord').on('change', function(){
   this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
 $("#formreg").submit(function(event) {
```

you are adding a new form submit listener inside your change listener.

```
$('#acord').on('change', function(){ ... }).change();
```

you are also triggering a change event immediately after registering your change listener (which as we saw above will add a submit listener to your form).

you are then, I assume, filling out your form and manually clicking `#accord` which will add a second submit listener to your form. you then submit the form, and your two handlers both get called.